# Visual Basic in Word: compare selection within range

Tags: vba, ms-word, named-ranges

UPDATE: Following the suggestion of Cindy below, I used the InRange function. My function iterates fine through the Find operation. But the function is failing to return FALSE when the selection is outside the named range.  See "FAILING HERE" below. Thanks.

Using Visual Basic, I need to validate whether the selection location in a Word document is within a named range.  Many years ago, I used this code to do that:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("typdef").Select

While ((WordBasic.CmpBookmarks("\Sel", "typedef") = 8 _
Or WordBasic.CmpBookmarks("\Sel", "typedef") = 6 _
Or WordBasic.CmpBookmarks("\Sel", "typedef") = 10) _
And leaveloop <> 1
...
If WordBasic.CmpBookmarks("\Sel", "\EndOfDoc") = 0 Then
    leaveloop = 1
End If
Wend
```

Here's the updated function I wrote:

```
Function FormatSpecHeadReturn(strStyle)

Dim rngBookmark As Word.Range
Dim rngSelection As Word.Range

Set rngBookmark = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SpecBodyPairRange").Range
Set rngSelection = Selection.Range

var = rngSelection.InRange(rngBookmark)
Debug.Print var

Do While rngSelection.InRange(rngBookmark) = True

Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(strStyle)
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.HomeKey

' FAILING HERE: Returns TRUE when selection point 
' is outside SpecBodyPairRange
var = rngSelection.InRange(rngBookmark)
Debug.Print var

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
Selection.InsertBefore Chr(182)
Selection.EndKey
Selection.InsertAfter vbTab
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove

    If rngSelection.InRange(rngBookmark) <> True Then Exit Do
  Loop
End Function
```

I was using CmpBookmarks in this current project, but it did not reliably returning the value of the current location. When the selection point is within the named range, it returns 8 for two loops, and then returns 6. When the selection point is outside the named range, CmpBookmarks returns 6.

Obviously, CmpBookmarks is deprecated. I can't find the return values that CmpBookmarks produces, and I can't find a modern equivalent function.

I confess I don't understand the difference between the named "SpecBodyPairRange" range and the range assigned to r, here:

Dim r As Range

I can see that "r" in this instance appears to hold the entire document. I studied Range Interface and Selection Interface on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, which I don't yet fully understand. I'm not a programmer, only a semi-technical writer self-taught in some coding who has the task of automating document conversion.

There must be a better way to compare the selection point to validate if it's within a named range, but I can't find it.  Any pointers you can give me are sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not a big Word VBA person but can you just compare the `Start` and `End` properties?

```
Dim bm As Bookmark

Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("tester")
Debug.Print "Bookmark", bm.Start, bm.End
Debug.Print "Selection", Selection.Start, Selection.End
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine whether one `Range` is within another use the `InRange` method:

```
Dim rngBookmark as Word.Range
Dim rngSelection as Word.Range

Set rngBookmark = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("typeDef").Range
Set rngSelection = Selection.Range
If rngSelection.InRange(rngBookmark) = True Then
  'Do something
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me understand ranges better!

Comment: thanks for the input and idea. I've implemented your suggestion. However, it's failing for unknown reasons. One strange things that's happening is that the range SpecBodyPairRange is arbitrarily changed as the function executes, apparently collapsed to an insertion point.

Comment: @montereyredfox Well, I did answer your original question. But your *real* question appears to be something else: how to search only the bookmarked range? That's a totally different thing and correctly should be a different question. It's considered "bad form" on Stack Overflow to change the question in such a way that people have to start over with answering - which is what happens when you change your code with what's in an Answer then say "I have a new problem".

Comment: But FWIW @montereyredfox it's because you never reassign `rngSelection` inside the loop. Run the `Find` on that instead of on `Selection`.

Comment: thanks for the input and update on StackOverflow good behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VBA's InRange Method. For example:

```
Function FormatSpecHeadReturn(strStyle)
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Bookmarks("SpecBodyPairRange").Range
  With .Bookmarks("SpecBodyPairRange").Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "^p"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Style = strStyle
      .Format = True
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
      .Style = "SpecHead"
      .Paragraphs.First.InsertBefore Chr(182)
      .InsertAfter vbTab
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End With
End Function
```

Comment: This is great, it vastly simplifies what I'm trying to do. However, it doesn't iterate through the entire range.

Comment: @montereyredfox The code *does* iterate through the entire range spanned by the 'SpecBodyPairRange' bookmark; I suggest you re-check what that range spans and what Styles are used within it.